# Defining a Sheaf of functions on a basis of open sets.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm having problems finishing the proof of lemma 2.1 in Perrin's Algebraic Geometry.

I have to prove that if we have a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ defined on a basis of open sets of $X$,we can set:

$\overline{\mathcal{F}}$$(U)$=$\{$s:$U$ $\rightarrow$$K$| $\forall$i, $s$$|_{U_i}$ $\in$ $\mathcal{F}$$(U_i)$$\}$

And this definition is independent of the choice of open cover $U_i$.

I think if we take another open cover of $U$ functions should agree on intersections but I don't know really how to write it down in a proper way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(V_j)$ be another open covering of $U$ and let $\bar{\mathcal{F}}(U)=\{s:U\rightarrow K|\forall j, s|_{V_i}\in\mathcal{F}(V_j)\}$. For $s\in\overline{\mathcal{F}}(U)$, let's prove that $s\in\bar{\mathcal{F}}(U)$, that is, we have to check that $s|_{V_j}\in \mathcal{F}(V_j)$ for all $j$. Given $j$, we have $V_i=\cup_i (V_j\cap U_i)$. We write $V_j\cap U_i=\cup_kW_{ijk}$ where $W_{ijk}$ are member of the basis. To prove that $s|_{V_j}\in\mathcal{F}(V_j)$ it is enough to prove that $s|_{W_{ijk}}$ for all $i,k$ and this is clear because $W_{ijk}\subset U_i$. We conclude that $\overline{\mathcal{F}}(U)\subset\bar{\mathcal{F}}(U)$ and by a similar argument we have $\bar{\mathcal{F}}(U)\subset \overline{\mathcal{F}}(U)$.